Expo React Native Error With Navigator, Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another
I recently upgraded from SDK 51 to SDK 52. I had to upgrade several libraries, and before my code worked fine, what I find after upgrading, is that the routing, has been broken, and gives me an error, which I do not see any sense, right now I have the version
"@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^7.0.2",
"expo": "52.0.7"

Now, I have created my app with Expo, and my input file is in app/_layout.tsx. In this file, I have a condition to know if there is user loaded, if so, it enters in the user panel, where I have a drawer, and if not, it enters in the Stack.Navigator where the Stack.Screen of the registry and log-in are.
return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={tamaguiConfig}>
      <Theme name="light">
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
          <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            {user ? (
              <DrawerLayout /> // Render Drawer if logged in
            ) : (
              <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Login"
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  component={Login}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Register"
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  component={RegisterHandler}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            )}
          </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </Theme>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  )

In my file <drawerlayout>, I have the user panel with the routes </drawerlayout>
const DrawerLayout = () => {
  const [newRecipeGenerated, setNewRecipeGenerated] = useState(false);

  return (
    <NewRecipeGenerationContext.Provider value={{ newRecipeGenerated, setNewRecipeGenerated }}>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Generación Recetas" component={RecipeGeneration} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Mis Recetas" component={UserRecipes} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NewRecipeGenerationContext.Provider>
  );
}

The thing is, I'm getting this error all the time:

Warning: Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, wrap the container in 'NavigationIndependentTree' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.

But I only have created one NavigationContainer, and it is in the _layout.tsx file!
I don't understand why it complains that there are more. If someone can tell me why this is so, I would be very grateful.
Edit: I searched in all projects for NavigationContainer, and it's only used in _layout.tsx
I just saw this from a blog:

Also Keep on mind: If you create your app with npx create-expo-app@latest --with-router, in this case a default navigation container is added and it causes the issue when adding NavigationContainer.

Maybe that's why...
New changes, I have removed the Navigation that wraps the _layout. and now I get another different error.....
Este es mi codigo del _layout principal
return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={tamaguiConfig}>
      <Theme name="light">
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
              <DrawerLayout /> // Render Drawer if logged in
            ) : (
              <Stack>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="(drawer)"
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="auth"
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
              </Stack>
            )}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </Theme>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  )

But I get an error ..
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
This error is located at:
in HomePage (created by SceneView)


Ensure there in only one NavigationContainer. Verify by checking in the folder app/_layout.tsx. If any of your navigators or components like DrawerLayout or any of the Stack.Screen components include another NavigationContainer, then remove it.

Remove the independent={true} prop if it is not required. This prop makes the navigation container operate independently from others, but in most cases, you do not need it. Ensure you are not using it unless necessary.

Check DrawerLayout component, verify that DrawerLayout or any child navigators don’t include a NavigationContainer. The Drawer should be inside the main NavigationContainer in app/_layout.tsx.



I have uploaded the DrawerLayout, and i dont have any other NavigationContainer :/

Check with npm ls @react-navigation/native or yarn list @react-navigation/native
. If there is duplication in dependency , for me it was something like
├─ @react-navigation/native@6.1.18
└─ expo-router@4.0.6
   └─ @react-navigation/native@7.0.3

so i removed the later and it works now

i recently upgraded my app to SDK 52

In mi case i have this with the ls.
+-- @react-navigation/drawer@7.0.3 | -- @react-navigation/native@7.0.2 deduped +-- @react-navigation/elements@2.0.2 | -- @react-navigation/native@7.0.2 deduped +-- @react-navigation/native-stack@7.0.2 |-- @react-navigation/native@7.0.2 deduped +-- @react-navigation/native@7.0.2 -- expo-router@4.0.5   +-- @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@7.0.3   |-- @react-navigation/native@7.0.2 deduped   -- @react-navigation/native@7.0.2 deduped

the most plausible reason could be that expo by default wraps ur whole app with NavigationContainer and since you are Wrapping it again this might be reason for it .
In my app i didnt wrap my root _layout with this NavigationContainer.

I got the error when migrating in version 52, before in version 51 it didn't happen to me, it looks like it, I've seen that expo by default wraps everything .... I'm going crazy with all these changes :/

I wasnt getting the error in SDK 51 but in SDK 52 .
Probably will be fixed in new releases

The problem was in the package.json
It turns out that when updating to expo version 52.0.7, I did not finish updating all the libraries related to routing to the new version to be compatible.
The command that updated it automatically (in theory) did not work, so I have updated it manually, and I had to put the versions correctly, especially the expo router and react-navigation/drawer.

What did you need to update?
